# How can I get the UTC time when I query mongodb in golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am relatively new to Golang and MongoDB and ran into a date issue where it appears that I can insert a UTC date into MongoDB, but when I query through Golang it is getting automatically converted to the local time. I want to get it back from MongoDB in UTC with no conversion. Here is a quick example:

```
type SampleItem struct {
    ObjId      bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"-"`
    SampleDate time.Time     `bson:"sampleDate" json:"sampleDate"`
}

func TestMe() {

    var item SampleItem
    var items []SampleItem

    sess := getSession()
    defer sess.Close()

    item.SampleDate = time.Now().UTC()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", item.SampleDate)

    collection := sess.DB("myCollection").C("sampleItems")
    collection.Insert(item)

    err := collection.Find(bson.M{}).All(&items)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", items[0].SampleDate)
    }
}
```

My output:

> 2014-10-12 04:10:50.3992076 +0000 UTC
>
> 2014-10-11 23:10:50.399 -0500 CDT

It appears that the mgo driver may be automatically converting it because when I query mongodb from a console window my date is in UTC. Am I missing a mgo option somewhere that turns this off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go [time.Time](http://godoc.org/time#Time) values store an instant in time and a location. The mgo BSON decoder sets the location to [time.Local](http://godoc.org/time#Local).

You can set `time.Local` to the UTC location:

```
time.Local = time.UTC
```

A package designed to be used third parties should not modify the local location, but it's OK within the scope of an application.

The [Time.UTC()](http://godoc.org/time#Time.UTC) method returns a time at the same instant in time as the receiver and the location set to UTC. This line will print the time in UTC:

```
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", items[0].SampleDate.UTC())
```

Because MongoDB stores time with lower precision than a time.Time, the value returned from MongoDB may not equal the value you stored.

Comment: OK. Part of my problem is that I am serializing to json, something like this:
data, err := json.Marshal(items[0]);
The json data is the wrong time. How can I get my json output to serialize in UTC?

Comment: I like the simplicity Charlie, but do wish there was a way I didn't have to remember to set to UTC before serializing to json. I looked into creating a custom type from time.Time which would allow me to set a custom json serializer that uses UTC. I'll post it as a possible answer, but I am interested in any comments from those with more experience on whether it is a good option or not.

Comment: That is exactly the type of thing I was looking for. Seems like it gets me what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Do we just put `time.Local = time.UTC` somewhere in our `main` package? There's not a lot of detail here in how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know I asked this question, but after lots of digging around I found this to be one possible option. By using a custom type from time.Time you can override the json serializer interfaces and force the use of UTC. However, is doing this type of thing recommended...

I have to give some credit to [UNIX time stamps in Golang](https://medium.com/coding-and-deploying-in-the-cloud/time-stamps-in-golang-abcaf581b72f) as well as the go source.

```
type JsonTime time.Time

func (t JsonTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    tt := time.Time(t).UTC()
    if y := tt.Year(); y < 0 || y >= 10000 {
        return nil, errors.New("JsonTime: year outside of range [0,9999]")
    }
    if y := tt.Year(); y == 1 {
        return []byte{}, nil
    }
    return []byte(tt.Format(`"` + time.RFC3339Nano + `"`)), nil
}

func (t JsonTime) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    if time.Time(t).IsZero() {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return time.Time(t), nil
}

func (t *JsonTime) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) error {
    var tm time.Time

    if err := raw.Unmarshal(&tm); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *t = JsonTime(tm)
    return nil
}

func (t JsonTime) String() string {
    return time.Time(t).UTC().String()
}

type SampleItem struct {
    ObjId      bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"-"`
    SampleDate JsonTime      `bson:"sampleDate" json:"sampleDate"`
}

func TestMe() {

    var item SampleItem
    var items []SampleItem

    sess := getSession()
    defer sess.Close()

    item.SampleDate = JsonTime(time.Now().UTC())
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", item.SampleDate)

    collection := sess.DB("myCollection").C("sampleItems")
    collection.Insert(item)

    err := collection.Find(bson.M{}).All(&items)
    if err == nil {

        fmt.Printf("%s\n", items[0].SampleDate)
        if data, err := json.Marshal(items); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", data)
        }
    }
}
```